# iOS - Scroll View/Paging Delegates/DataSource not being called

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, datasource, paging

I am using a UIScrollView to do paging and I noticed that none of the subsequent views that I page to get their datasource/delegates called. I have it hooked up in their XIB as datasource/delegate as well as having it in the code to be setup that way, but it's still not being called.

I am guessing the problem is here... where I am doing the paging and insert the 2nd and 3rd views. Both delegate/datasource are not working on 2nd or 3rd views being paged.

```
requestDetailTwoViewController *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];

requestDetailThreeViewController *controller2 = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null])
{
    if(page == 1)
    {

        controller = [[requestDetailTwoViewController alloc] initWithRequestNumber:[request objectForKey:@"RequestID"] forID:self.employeeIDfromHome];
        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
        CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * 1;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        controller.view.frame = frame;
        [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
    }
}

if ((NSNull *)controller2 == [NSNull null])
{
    if(page == 2)
    {
        controller2 = [[requestDetailThreeViewController alloc] initWithRequestNumber:[request objectForKey:@"RequestID"]];
        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller2];
        [self addChildViewController:controller2];
        CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * 2;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        controller2.view.frame = frame;
        [scrollView addSubview:controller2.view];
        [controller2 didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    }

}
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

In your class, have you set the hint for the protocol like

```
@interface myClass : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
...
```

And later, in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.myScrollView.delegate = self;
```